The magnetic force between the earth and the sun
There is a magnetic field around the earth and a stronger one around the sun. I guess there should be a magnetic force between the sun and earth. Now, shouldn't we take the magnetic force into account when trying to write an equation of motion of the earth? Honestly, I haven't see such a thing in the textbooks, just the gravitational force.

The magnetic force between the two is minuscule compared to the gravitational force.
We can get an order-of-magnitude estimate by treating both the sun and the Earth as ideal dipoles.  The force between two magnetic dipoles with dipole moments $m_\text{Sun}$ and $m_\text{Earth}$ will be on the order of
$$
F \approx \frac{\mu_0 m_\text{Sun} m_\text{Earth}}{4 \pi d^4}
$$
where $d = 1$ AU.  (The exact formula depends on the orientation but we're ignoring these factors to get an order of magnitude.)  These dipole moments are related to the fields created at the surface of each body by
$$
B_\text{Earth} \approx \frac{\mu_0 m_\text{Earth}}{4 \pi r_\text{Earth}^3}
$$
where $r_\text{Earth} = 6370$ km is the radius of the Earth, and similarly for the Sun.  Rearranging all of this allows us to express the force between the Sun and the Earth in terms of the magnetic fields near their surfaces as
$$
F \approx \frac{4 \pi}{\mu_0} \frac{B_\text{Earth} r_\text{Earth}^3 B_\text{Sun} r_\text{Sun}^3}{d^3}.
$$
The Sun's magnetic field is a few Gauss in the photosphere, or (order of magnitude) $10^{-3}$ T, while the Earth's surface magnetic field is about $5 \times 10^{-5}$ T (0.5 G.)  So whacking in all of these numbers, we find a magnetic force between the Earth and the sun of
$$
F \approx 90 \text{ N}
$$
which is utterly negligible compared to the gravitational force of about $3 \times 10^{22}$ N between the Sun and the Earth.

Hm... strange. If I model Earth-Sun system as attraction of two cylindrical bar magnets, where $L \approx R$, then I get that magnetic force between them is about on the order $F_{mag} \approx 10^{9}~N$. Bar magnets formula works only for identical pair of magnets, so I have used $B=0.5 \cdot (B_{earth} + B_{sun})$, same for magnet(s) length, I assumed it $L=0.5 \cdot (d_{sun} + d_{earth})$. Can it be that this different magnets averaging has involved such huge force computation error compared to yours ? If not, I can post my model.

Basically I have used approximated model : $$ F_{mag} \approx \frac{2 \pi {B_0}^{2} }{\mu_0}  \left(\frac{L^{4}}{\left(2 L + x\right)^{2}} - \frac{2 L^{4}}{\left(L + x\right)^{2}} + \frac{L^{4}}{x^{2}}\right)$$

I think my error can be that I assumed average area of magnetic pole(s) to be the average cross-section of Sun and Earth, which apparently is not the case. In reality magnetic poles area are much smaller than cosmic body cross section area. And since in magnetic force between bars expression pole area is taken squared, then my already big pole area error is amplified through $A^2$ part. Btw, it would be interesting to know real magnetic pole areas Sun vs Earth, so that I could re-calculate :-)
